# Is there a relationship between ocean tide and turbulence?

Tags: weather, turbulence

Especially at lower altitudes, can we asume that if the tide looks high that there would be more turbulence and vice versa?

Comment: Why would you think that?

Comment: because I've noticed it is windy when the tide is high and I wondered if that translated  to turbulence on the air just like choppy waters at sea level.

Comment: Well, high (onshore) winds can sometimes *cause* slightly-higher tides but it's normally a rather small effect compared to the normal range of the tides -- I really doubt that there's a robust correlation between tide height and wind speed generally --

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

In places such as the English Channel where tides cause strong tidal currents,
these can increase wind by as much as 1.5 m/s, or 3.5 mph
(Fig. 4 of Renault & Marchesiello,
"Ocean tides can drag the atmosphere and cause tidal winds over broad continental shelves,"
[*Nature Comm. Earth & Env.* 3: 70 (2022)](https://www.nature.com/articles/s43247-022-00403-y%5D).

But this is only within 800 m of the ocean surface,
and only where tides cause currents.
Also, a wind speed increase of 3.5 mph, from 0 to 3.5 or from 20 to 23.5,
is too small to increase turbulence enough to notice from even a small lightweight airplane.

High or low tide by itself, say
in the mid-Atlantic or mid-Canada (which moves up and
down too, "[crustal tide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_tide)"),
is too small in amplitude, and changes too slowly, to affect wind speed
nevermind the amount of turbulence.

Although tides are felt by not just sea and land but also the air,
these [lunar atmospheric tides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_tide#Lunar_atmospheric_tides)
affect wind even less.

Comment: Agreed, on the other hand, wind and low pressures affect sea level and tidal range in relation with the local geography (English Channel, Adriatic Sea, ..., 2m increase in the Baltic Sea). This is investigated, e.g. to improve tidal barrier operations: [Thames barrier](https://noc.ac.uk/files/documents/business/Tides-and-Meteorological-Effects.pdf) and [Venice barrier](https://tos.org/oceanography/assets/docs/33-1_ismar-team.pdf).

Comment: Sure, atmospheric phenomena ("weather") can affect local water level.  But the question sounds like it wants to infer how much turbulence there is, which you could do by observing the weather itself instead of something that it affects.